# EmbeddedKafka tests failing with java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: id

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test, embedded-kafka, nosuchfieldexception

When upgrading a component from Spring Boot 2.7.18 to Spring Boot 3.2.2, we are seeing all spring-kafka EmbeddedKafka tests fail with the following Spring initializationError:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: id

                at kafka.server.Defaults$.<clinit>(KafkaConfig.scala:187) ~[kafka_2.13-3.6.1.jar:na]

                at kafka.server.KafkaConfig$.<clinit>(KafkaConfig.scala:746) ~[kafka_2.13-3.6.1.jar:na]

                at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.DeleteTopicEnableProp(KafkaConfig.scala) ~[kafka_2.13-3.6.1.jar:na]

                at org.springframework.kafka.test.EmbeddedKafkaKraftBroker.addDefaultBrokerPropsIfAbsent(EmbeddedKafkaKraftBroker.java:256) ~[spring-kafka-test-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]

                at org.springframework.kafka.test.EmbeddedKafkaKraftBroker.afterPropertiesSet(EmbeddedKafkaKraftBroker.java:202) ~[spring-kafka-test-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]

                at org.springframework.kafka.test.context.EmbeddedKafkaContextCustomizer.customizeContext(EmbeddedKafkaContextCustomizer.java:130) ~[spring-kafka-test-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]

                at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextCustomizerAdapter.initialize(SpringBootContextLoader.java:442) ~[spring-boot-test-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]

                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:627) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]

                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:400) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]

                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]

                at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137) ~[spring-boot-test-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]

                at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58) ~[spring-core-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]

                at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:46) ~[spring-core-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]

                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1454) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]

                at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:552) ~[spring-boot-test-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
```

Has anyone seen this or have any suggestions for how to resolve it?

From the stack trace, we see it cannot find an "id" field.

But not sure what this "id" is.

How can we troubleshoot spring-kafka code which is invoking scala code?  The line numbers in Intellij console don't seem to map to the actual scala code.

The original versions used with Spring Boot 2.7.18:
spring-kafka 2.9.13, kafka-clients 3.2.3

The versions used with Spring Boot 3.2.2:
spring-kafka 3.1.1, kafka-clients 3.6.1

Here is a list of the dependencies/versions being used with Spring Boot 3.2.2.

```
dependencies {

    api platform (group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-dependencies', version: "3.2.2")

 

    api (group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-configuration-processor')

    api (group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator')

    api (group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc')

    api (group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-json')

    api (group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web')

    api (group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-security')

    api (group: 'org.springframework.kafka', name: 'spring-kafka')

 

    api (group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '33.0.0-jre')

    api (group: 'com.sapiens.bdms', name: 'bdms-java-exe-helper', version: '7.1')

    api (group: 'jakarta.validation', name: 'jakarta.validation-api', version: '3.0.2')

    api (group: 'org.ehcache', name: 'ehcache', version: '3.10.8')

    api (group: 'org.apache.avro', name: 'avro', version: '1.11.3')

    api (group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents.client5', name: 'httpclient5', version: '5.3')

    api (group: 'org.hibernate.validator', name: 'hibernate-validator', version: '8.0.1.Final')

 

    api (group: 'redis.clients', name: 'jedis', version: '5.1.0')

 

    implementation (group: 'org.apache.tika', name: 'tika-core', version: '2.9.1')

 

    // lombok

    implementation (group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: "1.18.30")

    annotationProcessor (group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: "1.18.30")

    testImplementation (group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: "1.18.30")

    testAnnotationProcessor (group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: "1.18.30")

 

    testImplementation (group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2')

    testImplementation (group: 'org.wiremock', name: 'wiremock', version: '3.3.1'){

        exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-api'

    }

    testImplementation (group: 'io.confluent', name: 'kafka-avro-serializer', version: '7.5.1')

    testImplementation (group: 'io.micrometer', name: 'micrometer-registry-prometheus', version: '1.12.1')

    testImplementation (group: 'it.ozimov', name: 'embedded-redis', version: '0.7.3'){

        exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-simple'

    }

    testImplementation (group: 'org.awaitility', name: 'awaitility', version: '4.2.0')

    testImplementation (group: 'jakarta.el', name: 'jakarta.el-api', version: '5.0.1')

    testImplementation (group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test')

    testImplementation (group: 'org.springframework.kafka', name: 'spring-kafka-test')

    testImplementation (group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-aop')

    testImplementation (group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.13.2')

 

    testImplementation('org.scala-lang:scala3-library_3:3.3.1')

}
```

We have other components on Spring Boot 3.2.2 that are successfully running EmbeddedKafka tests.

I have compared dependency trees, and have yet to find a difference that would cause the NoSuchFieldError.

Comment: It looks like some dependency-related issues. Can you provide a small project where the issue is reproduced?

Comment: I wonder if that `io.confluent:kafka-avro-serializer` brings some unexpected dependency which overrides whatever we would expect from the `org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test`...

Comment: Hi Artem:
You are correct!
I just finished creating a small sample to share and then saw your post.
When I remove the confluent dependency, all is well.
I'll dig in to understand why the code needs that dependency, and try to find potential alternative options.